# How do I make an asynchronous function call from another function?

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

**The goal is to create a docx document in parallel with the process of executing the rest of the program.**

The "first" function should just call the asynchronous "second" which will create the docx.
Now i use modules asyncio, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures, but isn't create the docx:

```
def first(self, event):
    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_in_executor(pool, self.second)

async def second(self):
    document = Document()
    document.save('test.docx')
```

I'm sure the problem is with the "first" function, the way it calls "second", but one man said to me, that it's not the fault of asynchrony. Until I found the closest method to the solution, I was constantly faced with the problem that the document is created only after the completion of the entire program execution process - that's not the goal.

I'm working on an old project that doesn't have time to fix; there are a lot of errors in basic things inside, so the browser didn't help - it need something specific for the situation. Even so, please tell me how to solve the problem.
Thanks.

Comment: If you just need to make one function call in parallel you shouldn't use `asyncio`. Just use `concurrent.futures`.

Comment: @giacomo-alzetta, please tell me how I can do this on the example of the above code?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to create `second` async. I will presume that you can change it to regular function.

You probably just want to start file creation in background OS thread:

```
def first():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        fut = executor.submit(second)  # start `second` in background

        # rest of the program

        fut.result()  # make sure `second` is finished


def second():
    document = Document()
    document.save('test.docx')
```

In case bottleneck is disk I/O this should do the trick. In case bottleneck is CPU, you should consider using [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) instead of `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

---

Here's reproducible code to play with:

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def first():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        fut = executor.submit(second)  # start `second` in background

        print('Rest of the program started')
        time.sleep(2)  # rest of the program
        print('Rest of the program finished')

        fut.result()  # make sure `second` is finished


def second():
    time.sleep(1)  # create doc
    print('Doc created')


first()
```